# How to input values into different entry boxes using buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I am incredibly new to python and I am trying to make a program that can track the stats of team members in a basketball game. I have no issues with the design but the functionality is a struggle and I am unsure as how to have it so that I can press the button and assign the correct points and stats to the correct team members.

I want to be able to select the entry boxes and then press one of the buttons to add points/stats OR use the menu function and have it work that way.

[image: I want to be able to select the entry boxes and then press one of the buttons to add points/stats OR use the menu function and have it work that way.]

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
 
newWindow=Tk()
newWindow.title("Stats")
newWindow.geometry("665x300")
newWindow.configure(bg='light blue')
  
Label(newWindow, text ="", bg='light blue').grid(row=9, column=1)
twoButton = Button(newWindow,text = '2pt +').grid(row=10, column=3)
threeButton = Button(newWindow,text = '3pt +').grid(row=10, column=4)
assistButton = Button(newWindow,text = 'Assist +').grid(row=10, column=5)
reboundButton = Button(newWindow,text = 'Rebound +').grid(row=10, column=6)
stealButton = Button(newWindow,text = 'Steal +').grid(row=10, column=7)
blockButton = Button(newWindow,text = 'Block +').grid(row=10, column=8)
turnoverButton = Button(newWindow,text = 'Turnover +').grid(row=10, column=9) 

Label(newWindow, text ="john:", bg='light blue').grid(row=2, column=1)
Label(newWindow, text ="simon:", bg='light blue').grid(row=3, column=1)
Label(newWindow, text ="joel:", bg='light blue').grid(row=5, column=1)
Label(newWindow, text ="kaur:", bg='light blue').grid(row=6, column=1)
Label(newWindow, text ="genom:", bg='light blue').grid(row=7, column=1)
Label(newWindow, text ="kieran:", bg='light blue').grid(row=8, column=1)

Label(newWindow, text ="2pts:", bg='light blue').grid(row=1, column=2)
Label(newWindow, text ="3pts:", bg='light blue').grid(row=1, column=3)
Label(newWindow, text ="Assists:", bg='light blue').grid(row=1, column=4)
Label(newWindow, text ="Rebounds:", bg='light blue').grid(row=1, column=5)
Label(newWindow, text ="Steals:", bg='light blue').grid(row=1, column=6)
Label(newWindow, text ="Blocks:", bg='light blue').grid(row=1, column=7)
Label(newWindow, text ="Turnovers:", bg='light blue').grid(row=1, column=8)

johnTwoP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=2, column=2)    
johnThreeP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=2, column=3)    
johnAssists = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=2, column=4)
johnRebounds = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=2, column=5)
johnSteals = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=2, column=6)
johnBlocks = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=2, column=7)
johnTO = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=2, column=8)

simonTwoP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=3, column=2)
simonThreeP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=3, column=3)
simonAssists = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=3, column=4)
simonRebounds = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=3, column=5)
simonSteals = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=3, column=6)
simonBlocks = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=3, column=7)
simonTO = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=3, column=8)

joelTwoP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=5, column=2)
joelThreeP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=5, column=3)
joelAssists = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=5, column=4)
joelRebounds = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=5, column=5)
joelSteals = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=5, column=6)
joelBlocks = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=5, column=7)
joelTO = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=5, column=8)

kaurTwoP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=6, column=2)
kaurThreeP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=6, column=3)
kaurAssists = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=6, column=4)
kaurRebounds = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=6, column=5)
kaurSteals = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=6, column=6)
kaurBlocks = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=6, column=7)
kaurTO = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=6, column=8)

genomTwoP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=7, column=2)
genomThreeP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=7, column=3)
genomAssists = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=7, column=4)
genomRebounds = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=7, column=5)
genomSteals = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=7, column=6)
genomBlocks = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=7, column=7)
genomTO = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=7, column=8)

kieranTwoP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=8, column=2)
kieranThreeP = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=8, column=3)
kieranAssists = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=8, column=4)
kieranRebounds = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=8, column=5)
kieranSteals = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=8, column=6)
kieranBlocks = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=8, column=7)
kieranTO = Entry(newWindow, width = 2, state = 'readonly').grid(row=8, column=8)

selectPlayer = StringVar()
selectPlayer.set("Player")
menu = OptionMenu(newWindow, selectPlayer,"john", "simon", "joel", "kaur", "genom", "kieran").grid(row=10, column=1)

newWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can pass the number to the button callback

Comment: First of all, all the entry variables are `None` because they are the result of `.grid(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`Button(newWindow, text='2pt +', command=lambda: click(1))`

create a button callback function and pass the value of the button to the function

**Your buttons should look like this**

```
def click(a):
    print(a)

twoButton = Button(newWindow, text='2pt +', command=lambda: click(1)).grid(row=10, column=3)
threeButton = Button(newWindow, text='3pt +', command=lambda: click(2)).grid(row=10, column=4)
assistButton = Button(newWindow, text='Assist +', command=lambda: click(3)).grid(row=10, column=5)
reboundButton = Button(newWindow, text='Rebound +', command=lambda: click(4)).grid(row=10, column=6)
stealButton = Button(newWindow, text='Steal +', command=lambda: click(5)).grid(row=10, column=7)
blockButton = Button(newWindow, text='Block +', command=lambda: click(6)).grid(row=10, column=8)
turnoverButton = Button(newWindow, text='Turnover +', command=lambda: click(7)).grid(row=10, column=9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary of player names with values as row number of the players. You can then use `.grid_slaves(row, column)` to get the widget at that location.

This should be your function to increment points

```py
def addPoints(column):

    widget = newWindow.grid_slaves(row=playerDic[selectPlayer.get()], column=column)[0]

    currentScore = widget.get()

    if currentScore == '':
        currentScore = 0

    widget['state'] = 'normal'
    widget.delete(0, 'end')
    widget.insert(0, int(currentScore) + 1)
    widget['state'] = 'readonly'
```

your OptionMenu:

```py
selectPlayer = StringVar()
selectPlayer.set("john")

playerDic = {"john": 2, "simon": 3, "joel": 5, "kaur": 6, "genom": 7, "kieran": 8} # row values

menu = OptionMenu(newWindow, selectPlayer, *playerDic.keys()).grid(row=10, column=1)
```

and your buttons must pass the column numbers. Something like this:

```py
twoButton = Button(newWindow,text = '2pt +', command=lambda :addPoints(2)).grid(row=10, column=3)
threeButton = Button(newWindow,text = '3pt +', command=lambda :addPoints(3)).grid(row=10, column=4)
assistButton = Button(newWindow,text = 'Assist +', command=lambda :addPoints(4)).grid(row=10, column=5)
reboundButton = Button(newWindow,text = 'Rebound +', command=lambda :addPoints(5)).grid(row=10, column=6)
stealButton = Button(newWindow,text = 'Steal +', command=lambda :addPoints(6)).grid(row=10, column=7)
blockButton = Button(newWindow,text = 'Block +', command=lambda :addPoints(7)).grid(row=10, column=8)
turnoverButton = Button(newWindow,text = 'Turnover +', command=lambda :addPoints(8)).grid(row=10, column=9)
```

Note: if you change the row or column of the entry widget don't forget to update the dictionary and the column number in `command=lambda :addPoints(column)`

<sub>On a side note: you should also know that all the variables that you assigned `<widget>.grid()` is `None` since `.grid()` returns `None` so all your variables are pretty much useless.</sub>